# fatal error :"python.h" no file or directory?

Tags: python, compiling, g++

While looking for a solution for the [Hungarian problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), I found [this GitHub link](https://github.com/hrldcpr/hungarian).

I went through the `readme.md` file and I performed everything described there. After copying `hungarian.so` into my working directory, when I tried to compile `hungarian.cpp` using `make hungarian`, I got this output:

```
anupam@JAZZ:~/Python/hungarian-master$ make hungarian
g++     hungarian.cpp   -o hungarian
hungarian.cpp:7:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [hungarian] Error 1
```

I found [this related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory), but the answer didn't work for me.

I am very new to GitHub I don't know how to add modules on `g++`. Can someone help me with that, and what to do next?

Comment: So running `sudo apt-get install python-dev` did not work?

Comment: yeah ,, @Salem it didn,t worked for me..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After looking at https://github.com/hrldcpr/hungarian/blob/master/hungarian.cpp, it seems that you need both:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
```

So install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev python-numpy
```

To identify the missing packages (the ones providing the headers), look at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Python.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).

Comment: ,I had this too installed ,,,libpython2.7-dev is already the newest version.

Comment: @jazzz: Since you installed `python-dev` you now have `libpython2.7-dev` as well as it's a dependency of `python-dev`. Problem solved isn't it?

Comment: @jazz You can check the packages dependencies here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-dev and http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpython-dev

Comment: Thanx @Sylvain Pineau ,,well meanwhile I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041299/python-h-no-such-file-or-directory  ,and in one of the comment I got Most likely Python.h is not in your build systems' include path. You can find out where your Python.h is by running

dpkg -L python-dev | grep Python.h                               and when I tried this on my system I am getting nothig???         anupam@JAZZ:~/Python/hungarian-master$ dpkg -L python-dev | grep Python.h
anupam@JAZZ:~/Python/hungarian-master$ 
how can I resolve it??

Comment: Thanx @Sylvain Pineau ,,well meanwhile I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041299/python-h-no-such-file-or-directory  ,and in one of the comment I got Most likely Python.h is not in your build systems' include path. You can find out where your Python.h is by running

dpkg -L python-dev | grep Python.h                               and when I tried this on my system I am getting nothig???         anupam@JAZZ:~/Python/hungarian-master$ dpkg -L python-dev | grep Python.h
anupam@JAZZ:~/Python/hungarian-master$ 
how can I resolve it??

Comment: @jazzz Try with this command instead: `dpkg-query -L libpython2.7-dev | grep Python.h`

Comment: I got this: /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17315/discussion-between-jazzz-and-sylvain-pineau).

Comment: Hi, I was trying to install certain Python external modules via pip, and I came across a similar error, so I came to this page, and it said to install `libpython2.7-dev` and `python-dev`. I had `python-dev` already installed but apparently not `libpython2.7-dev`, and installing it fixed the issues. Why? What is in `libpython2.7-dev`, and why isn't it included by default?

Answer (score 19):

For Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
```

You can also install it for specific versions of Python (if available for your version of Ubuntu, or from a PPA):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

The `python3-dev` package depends on a `python3.x-dev` package, (where 3.x is the system version of Python) and on the `libpython3-dev` package, which in turn depends on a corresponding `libpython3.x-dev` package.

Comment: Fedora `dnf install python3.10-devel` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230444/how-to-install-python-developer-package

Answer (score 4):

This is python code [extending with C](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html). No need to use `make`. Python itself will take care of the `cpp` code compilation with proper flags.

First you need to have header files and a static library. Install those as,

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Now follow these commands to execute `example.py` in your code.

```
python setup.py build
cp  build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/hungarian.so .
python example.py
```

> **Note:** I am using `python2.7`, you should take care of your version of python when execute the above commands. It is worth mentioning that you need to install `python-numpy` if you not have it as python script need it.

Comment: Thanx @souravc ,it worked but when I run $python example.py it gives me          anupam@JAZZ:~/Python/hungarian-master$ python example.py
[1 2 0 4 5 3 7 6]
but I need to calculate the net Assignment profit,, here it is giving output for print  hungarian.lap(a)[0],, (what is this)?

Comment: @jazzz I have no idea about hungarian problem. I think they have provided the basic code `hungarian.cpp` and an example to execute some basic function of it in `eample.py`. If you need more you might have to write your own code.